# some problems with parsing arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, django

I have two arrays, for example, the first could be:

```
self.history = [[1, 15, 12, 51], [15, 5, 12, 4]]
```

and the second:

```
date = ["10.11.2014", "11.11.2014", "12.11.2014", "13.11.2014"]
```

I need to output the following type of format:

```
""10.11.2014,1,15\n" + "11.11.2014,15,5\n" + "12.11.2014,12,12\n" + "13.11.2014,51,4\n""
```

I had already achieved this result once but after a reboot it doesn't work anymore.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
        zips = zip(*self.history)
        zips2 = zip(date_arr, zips)
        print zips2
        zips = ['"{},{}\\n" + '.format(a, ','.join(b)) for a, b in zips2]
        for i in zips:
                returning = returning + i
        print returning
        self.history = returning
        return self.history
```

The following error is returned (in django): "sequence item 0: expected string, int found".
What is causing the error?

Comment: ["{},{}".format(d, ",".join([str(v) for v in h])) for d, h in zip(date, zip(*self.history)) -- You can "".join only sequence of strings

Comment: @kAlmAcetA, I've removed my post in favor of yours (as yours is even more pythonic), please consider making it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"\n".join(','.join(str(i) for i in x) for x in zip(date, *history))
```

Comment: +1: Best from the list so far, because it correctly uses the functionality of `zip` on more than 2 arguments and is the most readable too.

Comment: Use izip from the itertools module if you are using Python 2.X.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this part `join(b) for a, b in zips2`. the join(b) fails because b is a list of `int`s. You need to convert this list of `int`s into a list of `string`s before calling `join`.

Change this to:
`join((str(i) for i in b)) for a,b in zips2` and it should work.

Here's my answer:

```
history = [[1, 15, 12, 51], [15, 5, 12, 4]]
date = ["10.11.2014", "11.11.2014", "12.11.2014", "13.11.2014"]
result = []
for k, v in zip(date, zip(*history)):
    result.append('%s,%s\n' % (k, ','.join([str(a) for a in v])))

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [ ",".join(map(str,x))+'\n' for x in zip(date,*history) ]
['10.11.2014,1,15\n', '11.11.2014,15,5\n', '12.11.2014,12,12\n', '13.11.2014,51,4\n']
```

or

```
>>> " + ".join([ "\""+",".join(map(str,x))+"\n\"" for x in zip(date,*history) ])
'"10.11.2014,1,15\n" + "11.11.2014,15,5\n" + "12.11.2014,12,12\n" + "13.11.2014,51,4\n"'
```